# Universal Mobile number validation pattern in PHP

Tags: php, regex, explode, phone-number

Here is My working Code, if you got a better one post below.

Took me hours to build. 
Number can be between (4-15) Universal Standard.
Might contain '+' at the beginning and '-' is allowed once with allowed format like ('1+123,12+123,+1-123,+12-123). 
Rest all spaces and '-' and '+' will be replaced by blank and a proper Number will be returned.

```
public function validateMobileNumber($mobile){
     $mobile = str_replace(' ','',$mobile);//remove all the blank spaces i.e +1-123456342234
    //now let's do it for mobile numbers
    if(preg_match('/^([0-9,\\-,+,]){4,15}$/', $mobile)){//pratially valid number 
    $mobile = rtrim($mobile, "+");
    $mobile = trim($mobile, "-");
    //removing multiple '-'
    $mobile_arr = explode('-',$mobile);//elplode a number like +1-123 456-342-234
    $sub1 = $mobile_arr[0];//+1
    if(strlen($sub1) != strlen($mobile)){ // condition where 12345678 valid nos is detected
        $check_plus = explode('+',$sub1); //logic to detect number starts with +1-123.. or +12-123.. or 1-123.. or 12-123...
        if($check_plus[0] == ''){ // occurs when we get +1...
            if(strlen($sub1) == 2 || strlen($sub1) == 3){//valid digits like +1-123, +12-123
                unset($mobile_arr[0]);
            } else {
                //invlid number
                return array('status'=>'error','message'=>'Number must be in +1-123.. or +12-123.. or 1-123.. or 12-123... format');
            }
        } else {
            if(strlen($sub1) == 1 || strlen($sub1) == 2){//valid digits like 1-123, 12-123
                unset($mobile_arr[0]);
            } else {
                //invlid number
                return array('status'=>'error','message'=>'Number must be in 1-123.. or 12-123.. or +1-123.. or +12-123... format');
            }
        }

        $mobile = $sub1 .'-'.implode('',$mobile_arr);//+1-123 456342234
    }
    //removing '-' ends

    //removing '+'
    $mobile_arr = explode('+',$mobile);//explode a number like +1-123 456+342-234
    if($mobile_arr[0]!='') {
        if (strlen($mobile_arr[0]) != strlen($mobile)){ //number might be 1-123 456+342-234+
            return array('status'=>'error','message'=>'Number must have "+" at the start ');
        }
    } else {
        if($mobile_arr[2]!=''){//when we have more than one + 
            $sub1 = $mobile_arr[1];
            unset($mobile_arr[1]);
            $mobile = '+'.$sub1.implode('',$mobile_arr);//+1-123 456342234
        }
    }

    return array('status'=>'success','data'=>$mobile);
} else {
    return array('status'=>'error','message'=>'Invalid Mobile Number.');
}
//Validate Mobile number logic ends
```

}

Comment: If you want a code review, please try https://codereview.stackexchange.com. This site is for fixing bugs, but you state your code is working.

Comment: Did you have a question? If you just want to publish some code, Github is probably a better option.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: For what it's worth, this doesn't validate my mobile number correctly.

Comment: @iainn ... I did one change in that code. But if it's not working for you. Providing with something that does would make me really grateful!